# Vim syntax highlighting

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

Alright, this is probably a stupid question, but....

I've got a file of source code in a proprietary language. I want to edit said file with VIM, instead of their crummy editor. I'd like basic syntax highlighting of the language, but I don't want to spend a bunch of time rolling my own syntax file.

Therefore, does VIM have a basic source highlighting module? It doesn't need to be perfect, I just want it to cover simple things. Currently, my only choices are no syntax highlighting, pick a random language, or roll my own.

**EDIT:** Source code sample below

```
{
    function letter do
        gposition 0, 0
        if gender = "M" do
            if language = "SPA" OR state = "PR" do
                %male spanish letter
                gposition .26, .75
                pdfimage "MALE SPANISH.pdf", 1, .93

                setcolor truewhite
                setfillmode 1
                %whitebox
                gposition 5.25, 1.25
                rectangle 2.5, .5
```

Comment: What is the language like? What do you want highlighted? Just keywords, or structures, or more interesting things? Is it C-like in its overall feel? Or is it like Assembly code? Or XPM? (Now *there's* an interesting syntax file!)

Comment: @Chris Morgan Doh! It's a nasty little unique language called psl. Everything within {} is code, outside that, its an implicit print statement. There are basic control structures, comments started by a %, and the first word on every line is a command followed by the required inputs. I think of them as function calls without the parenthesis, so it looks kind of like shell syntax. But there are enough differences that shell highlighting looks off.

Comment: post example, quite simple to put together a rudimentary syntax file. 5 min. and then you have some basic stuff set up like comments and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could this be the correct language?

http://www.iml.ece.mcgill.ca/~stephan/node/17

Comment: good catch; setf vhdl or setf verilog should do the job. you might want to try different colorschemes with it

Comment: Sure doesn't look like it. There are no common keywords in it, and only ones like "function" and "if" (not even "do") in vhdl/verilog. @Spencer: that is, however, a good example of a nice simple syntax highlighter based (mostly) just on keywords.

Comment: While it isn't the same language, it does work as a simplistic starting point. I'll dump in the keywords list, add a line or two and be on my way. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Rolling your own syntax highlighting is *not* difficult at all and it would take a few minutes.

For example, I wrote a DSL (called Konira) that uses Python for the most part, but it fails at highlighting my custom DSL statements. This is how the "extra" highlighting looks:

```
function! KoniraSyntax() abort
    let b:current_syntax = 'konira'
    syn match KoniraIt                   '\v^\s+it\s+'
    syn match KoniraSkipIf               '\v^\s+skip\s+if'
    syn match KoniraDescribe             '\v^describe\s+'
    syn match KoniraRaises               '\v^\s+raises\s+'
    syn match KoniraBeforeAll            '\v^\s+before\s+all'
    syn match KoniraBeforeEach           '\v^\s+before\s+each'
    syn match KoniraAfterEach            '\v^\s+after\s+each'
    syn match KoniraAfterAll             '\v^\s+after\s+all'

    hi def link KoniraSkipIf             Statement
    hi def link KoniraIt                 Statement
    hi def link KoniraDescribe           Statement
    hi def link KoniraRaises             Identifier
    hi def link KoniraBeforeAll          Statement
    hi def link KoniraBeforeEach         Statement
    hi def link KoniraAfterAll           Statement
    hi def link KoniraAfterEach          Statement
endfunction
```

As you can see above, I set the current syntax, then I match via regular expression those
statements that I want, and the I apply the type of highlighting that I need on that match.

And you can call it as a regular function when you know (or if you able to detect) that you are editing such a source file:

```
call KoniraSyntax()
```