# How to define my own highlight colors to use with matchadd() in vim?

Tags: vim, macvim

I recently found [this little piece of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577579/task-tags-in-vim) for my `.vimrc`

```
if has("autocmd")
  " Highlight TODO, FIXME, NOTE, etc.
  if v:version > 701
    autocmd Syntax * call matchadd('Todo',  '\W\zs\(TODO\|FIXME\|CHANGED\|XXX\|BUG\|HACK\)')
    autocmd Syntax * call matchadd('Debug', '\W\zs\(NOTE\|INFO\|IDEA\)')
  endif
endif
```

Basically, it allows me to define keywords which are matched with different highlighting (Todo and Debug are the names of the colors).

Is there a way that I can define my own coloring schemes and give them names? Specifically what I want to have is 3 tags: TODO1, TODO2 and TODO3. The idea is that TODO3 is lower priority than TODO1 and thus is highlighted in a lighter shade.

If I can't define my own coloring, where can I find a list of the color names I can use?

Comment: I answered a similar question that might be able to help you out. It basically tells you how to define your own matching colors (on top of whatever colorscheme you are using): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386085/vim-syntax-highlighting/6388100#6388100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use default theme colors, here is the solution:

```
" Define autocmd for some highlighting *before* the colorscheme is loaded
augroup VimrcColors
au!
  autocmd ColorScheme * highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=darkgreen guibg=#444444
  autocmd ColorScheme * highlight Tab             ctermbg=darkblue  guibg=darkblue
augroup END
```

And later on (this **must** be after):

```
" Load color scheme
colorscheme yourscheme
```

Color definitions follow the format:

```
autocmd ColorScheme * highlight <ColorName> ctermbg=<TerminalBackgroundColour> guibg=<GuiBackgroundColour> ctermfg=<TerminalFontColor> guifg=<GuiFontColour>
```

Where the `cterm` colors must come from a predefined list (see `:help cterm-colors` for more info). Gui colors can be any Hex color.

Comment: Your `if !exists('var') | let var=1 | ... | endif` is naturally expressed by `augroup vimrcColors | autocmd! | ... | augroup END`. It has an advantage of you not being forced to unlet a variable and delete autocommands manually in order to reload them.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have seen it one day, but I did not get the advantage. I am going to give it a try!

Comment: @Plouff, Thanks a million for your answer. Perhaps you might edit with ZyX's suggestion? I don't really understand what he means.

Comment: Hi, glad it helped! I updated the solution with the comment of ZyX. The code is must more clean in this way. Thanks again

Comment: I updated the solution one more time since I forgot to remove the variable assignment... This should be the final answer.